# gcc 4.2.1 Linking issue: ATLAS 3.8.3

Tags: gcc, osx-snow-leopard, blas, atlas

I'm trying to use CBLAS ATLAS. I'm a beginner. I have the following C code.

```
// tmp.cpp file
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<cblas.h>

int main(void){
   float x[2] = {6,2};
   float *y = (float *)malloc(2*sizeof(float));
   const int n = 2;
   const int incx = 1;
   const int incy = 1;
   float a = 5.4;
   y[0] = 4.2; y[1] = 4.5;
   cblas_saxpy(n,a,x,incx,y,incy);
   free(y);
}
```

I installed the ATLAS library following the video http://youtu.be/DvLSr6zN0pU?t=6m5s and the next video "part3". However, I have no FORTRAN compiler, so I configure with

$../ATLAS/confiugre --nof77

The installation process took place as described in the video.

```
iMac:Desktop sotero$ ls /usr/local/atlas/include
atlas       cblas.h     clapack.h
iMac:Desktop sotero$ ls /usr/local/atlas/lib/
libatlas.a  libcblas.a  liblapack.a libptcblas.a
```

I tried compiling with this result

```
iMac:Desktop sotero$ c++ tmp.cpp
tmp.cpp:3:18: error: cblas.h: No such file or directory
tmp.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
tmp.cpp:14: error: ‘cblas_saxpy’ was not declared in this scope
```

I read how to make the link to the website http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/errata.html#LINK and I have the following to compile

```
iMac:Desktop sotero$ c++ tmp.cpp -L/usr/local/atlas/lib/ -lcblas -latlas -I/usr/local/atlas/include/
Undefined symbols:
  "cblas_saxpy(int, float, float const*, int, float*, int)", referenced from:
     _main in ccPop12J.o
ld: symbol(s) not found
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I do not know how I should compile. I just need to level one BLAS. I've been looking to compile if you do link to the ATLAS library, but I'm lost.

How I can fix it?

Comment: The link you pointed to says something about OS X, you seem to be on OS X (iMac: ...). Try this: c++ -I/usr/local/atlas/include/  tmp.cpp  /usr/local/atlas/lib/libcblas.a /usr/local/atlas/lib/libatlas.a